# What is the simplest way to align center on first component of two ordered component in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to align the red surface to the center of the page, how can i do that?

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Surface(
            color = Color.Red,
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp, 50.dp)
        ){}
        Surface(
            color = Color.Blue,
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp, 50.dp)
        ) {}
    }
}
```

View:

[image]

Want this:

[image]

Comment: You want red / blue on top of each other?

Comment: I added what I wanted to the question.

Comment: Where do you want Blue to go then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your blue view has a static size, just add `Spacer` of the same size on the other side.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    val blueViewWidth = 100.dp
    Spacer(Modifier.width(blueViewWidth))
    RedView()
    BlueView(Modifier.size(blueViewWidth, 50.dp))
}
```

If blue view size depends on content, you can use it instead of `Spacer` and apply `Modifier.alpha(0)` - this will be less performant than creating a custom layout, but should be perfectly fine, unless your view has a really huge layout to measure.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    BlueView(Modifier.alpha(0f))
    RedView()
    BlueView()
}
```

Comment: @MARSK In the real world, it probably won't just be a blue view, but will have some content, so `Color.Transparent` won't be enough. By dynamic size I mean wrapping the size of the content - it cannot be passed as a size because it is not defined before the first recomposition.

Comment: @MARSK it'll hide the whole view, but count it in size measuring

Comment: @MARSK that's true

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `Layout` if things need to be precisely positioned.

```
Layout(
 content = { Red(); Blue() } // Add Composables here
) { measurables, constraints ->
 layout(width = constraints.maxWidth, height = constraints.maxHeight) {
  measurables[0].measure(constraints).apply { //Red
   place(
    (constraints.maxWidth - width) / 2,
    (constraints.maxHeight - height) / 2  
   )
  }
  measurables[1].measure(constraints).apply {
   place(
    (constraints.maxWidth + width) / 2,
    (constraints.maxHeight - height) / 2
   )
  }
 }
}
```

That should just about do it, y'know provided that both Red AND Blue are of the same width. If not, you'll have to store the measurables' measure results in a variable instead of just using `apply`. But that is no hard job -- It's actually super easy, barely an inconvenience.

**EXPLANATION**:

We call a simple `Layout` Composable and pass our desired Composables to its `content` block, since those are what we have to position. Then, we are given access to those same composables in the form of `measurables`, which we can use to measure and place wherever we want. We also have a `constraints` parameter which are just like the dimensions of the screen in this case. We return a `layout` block, which is essentially a container for all the desired Composables, and we specify a width and a height, in this case max values for both of these dimensions, which corresponds to full screen here.

`measurables` is an array containing all the Composables in order they were passed to the `content` block. Hence, `measurables[0]` is the `Red` block and blue is on index 1. Now, we position the red block at precisely the center of the screen. Try tweaking the x and y values for a bit to see how the UI reacts. Afterwards we place Blue at an `x` equal to the `x` of `Red` + `Width` of `Red` (or blue, since they're the same here). We do this since we wish for blue to be placed exactly after `Red`. `x` is the distance from the edge of screen to the start (or left edge) of the Composable while `y` is from its top.

Comment: this answer is helpful but isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Well this is the recommended method for Compose, but you could also take a look into `ConstraintLayout` for Compose. The thing is, this seems complex since you do not understand what each line of code does, which confuses you. It is actually pretty simple. Lemme try and explain

Comment: See? Super-easy, barely an inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Layout` composable.
Something like:

```
Layout( content = {

    Surface(
        color = Color.Red,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp, 50.dp)
            .layoutId("red")
    ) {}
    Surface(
        color = Color.Blue,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp, 50.dp)
            .layoutId("blue")
    ) {}

}){ measurables, incomingConstraints ->

    val constraints = incomingConstraints.copy(minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0)
    val redPlaceable =
        measurables.find { it.layoutId == "red" }?.measure(constraints)
    val bluePlaceable =
        measurables.find { it.layoutId == "blue" }?.measure(constraints)

    //align red and blue
    layout(
        width = constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight)
        {
            val redPositionx = (constraints.maxWidth - widthOrZero(redPlaceable)) /2
            val redPositiony = (constraints.maxHeight - heightOrZero(redPlaceable)) /2
            redPlaceable?.placeRelative(redPositionx, redPositiony)
            bluePlaceable?.placeRelative(redPositionx+widthOrZero(redPlaceable), redPositiony)

    }
}
```

with:

```
internal fun widthOrZero(placeable: Placeable?) = placeable?.width ?: 0
internal fun heightOrZero(placeable: Placeable?) = placeable?.height ?: 0
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you think that is a bit overcomplicating the stuff for such a simple job? I mean we don't need the `layoutId`s in this context, which would wipe out the null safety indicators we'd have to write otherwise. Other than that, there's also no need for making the minimum dimensions of the Composables zero, unless there's something I'm missing. Other than that, I did learn something from the answer so upvote for that.

Comment: @MARSK Yes, you can simply use `measurables[i]` as described in your answer. In general I prefer to use the `layourId` as in many android material examples.It is useful to maintain the component in the future if you add another composables in the component or if you change the order of the composables.

Comment: And what about modifying the min dimensioned of the Composables? Does that help in any way in not aware of?

Comment: In this specific simple example it is not needed.